# How OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory can support both SignatureAlgorithm.RS256 and SignatureAlgorithm.RS512

Tags: spring-security

For resource server, it's as simple as

```
@Bean
fun jwtDecoder(): JwtDecoder {
    // makes a request to the JWK Set endpoint
    val jwsKeySelector: JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> = JWSAlgorithmFamilyJWSKeySelector.fromJWKSetURL<SecurityContext>(this.jwkSetUrl)
    val jwtProcessor: DefaultJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> = DefaultJWTProcessor()
    jwtProcessor.jwsKeySelector = jwsKeySelector
    return NimbusJwtDecoder(jwtProcessor)
}
```

and it fetches the algorithms from the public key endpoint.

But it doesn't work for OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory because https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.0.0-M6/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/authentication/OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory.java create a new `JwtDecoder`

Any idea? or I can only customize a `OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-idtoken-verify) is indeed the correct configuration hook for providing the algorithm used for a client in a custom way.

For example, you can specify the following:

```java
@Bean
public JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> idTokenDecoderFactory() {
    OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory idTokenDecoderFactory = new OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory();
    idTokenDecoderFactory.setJwsAlgorithmResolver(clientRegistration -> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> supportedAlgorithms =
                (List<String>) clientRegistration.getProviderDetails()
                        .getConfigurationMetadata()
                        .get("id_token_signing_alg_values_supported");
        return SignatureAlgorithm.from(supportedAlgorithms.get(0));
    });
    return idTokenDecoderFactory;
}
```

Note that this is a trivial example that assumes the first available algorithm. You can provide any logic you need, but it has to return a single algorithm.

There is some good background on this issue in [#11049](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11049).

Comment: Thx for your reply. Do you know why it has to return a single algorithm? because the decoder of resource server can support multiple

```
@Bean
fun jwtDecoder(): JwtDecoder {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri)
            .jwsAlgorithms {
                it.add(RS512)
                it.add(ES512)
            }.build()
}
```

Comment: See the link in my answer for more background on that.